# How do I assign a value to an array of strings in C?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

So I have used `malloc()` to create an array of pointers. I ultimately want to have an array of strings. How would I come about assigning a string value to one of these malloced pointers?

For example if I have done the following:

`char ** elements= malloc(N* sizeof(char*));`

and looped the previous array to malloc the individual pointers like this:

`elements[i] = malloc((50) * sizeof(char));`

Comment: This code will allocate exactly 50 bytes for each string.  Do you know that all your strings will be shorter than that?

Comment: For this code, you would want to use `strcpy(elements[i], somestring)` -- but, you would have to be careful to make sure each copied string `somestring` was less than 50 characters long.

Comment: I see, the strings would in fact be less than 50 characters long, thanks a lot!

Comment: There is a non-standard but widely available function `strdup`, check it out. You can implement your own version too.

Comment: C doesn't have string values. Only chars and pointers. So you have to figure out what "assign a value to an array of strings" means in actual C language (chars and pointers).

Answer (score 0):

We can copy something into the string using `strncpy()` and similair functions, for example `memcpy()` or using our own function.

I recommend using `strncpy()` since it protects against overflows because it copies a till a  length specified.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef unsigned char BYTE;

enum {
    NumStrings = 50,
    MaxStrLen = 50
};

int main(void) {
    char **StrList = malloc(NumStrings * sizeof(char *));
    if (StrList == NULL) {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (BYTE i = 0; i < NumStrings; i++) {
        StrList[i] = malloc(MaxStrLen);
        if (StrList[i] == NULL) {
            perror("malloc");
            exit(1);
        }
        // Here we copy something into the string for example
        strncpy(StrList[i], "test", 50);
        StrList[i][49] = '\0';
        // Print string here to show it's copied
        printf("%s ", StrList[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');

    for (BYTE i = 0; i < NumStrings; i++) 
        free(StrList[i]);
    free(StrList);
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately `strncpy` can cause just about as many problems as it solves, since if a source string happens to be exactly N characters long, the copied string won't be properly null-terminated.  The truly safe option, though it's not Standard, is [`strlcpy`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strlcpy).

Comment: "I recommend using strncpy() since it protects against overflows"  This is plain wrong. Please study [Is strcpy dangerous and what should be used instead?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/281518)

Comment: @SteveSummit `strcpy_s` is formally standardized, though in practice very few compilers implement the C11 bounds-checking library.

Answer (score 0):

With current standard C, you would do:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t size = strlen(some_string) + 1; // +1 for null term
elements[i] = malloc(size);
memcpy(elements[i], some_string, size);

...

free(elements[i]);
```

With the upcoming "C2x" standard (still in draft stages), `strdup` will likely get added to the language. Though it's already widely available as a non-standard extension supported by POSIX. Example:

```
#include <string.h>

elements[i] = strdup(some_strings[i]);

...

free(elements[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `#include <string.h>` to include string functions.
Than use `strncpy` function to assign a value to char array. To copy a string to `elements[i]`,  use this:

```
strncpy(elements[i], "Hello, world!", 49)
```

You can put another `char` array pointer as second argument. Please note, that to avoid erasing null-byte at the end of string, substract `1` from actual string array length to keep last byte for `'\0'`. Also, it's better to use `calloc(50, sizeof(char))` to allocate strings, because `calloc` additionally fills them with null bytes. Or, at least, add this line while iterating (set last byte to zero to make string null-terminated):

```
elements[i][49] = '\0';
```